# Type safe way of finding differences between 2 objects in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have 2 objects of the same type. I need to find all of the values from one object that either don't exist in the other, or have a different value.

This code works but has TypeScript errors:

```
export type Thing = {
  name?: string;
  age?: number;
  location?: {
    x: number,
    y: number
  }
};

const things: Thing = { name: "Jim", age: 32, location: {x:1, y:2} };
const things2: Thing = { name: "Jim" };

const things3: Thing = {};

Object.entries(things).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  if (things[key] !== things2[key]) {
    things3[key] = value;
  }
});
```

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Thing'.
> No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Thing'.ts(7053)

Ive reduced the number of errors by using the `ts-extras` library:

```
objectEntries(things).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  if (things[key] !== things2[key]) {
    things3[key] = value;
  }
});
```

But I still get this error by `things3[key] = value;`:

> (parameter) key: keyof Thing
> Type 'string | number | { x: number; y: number; } | undefined' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.
> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.ts(2322)

Comment: There is no way to do this in a compile-time type-safe way because you are using runtime reflection with `Object.entries`. You will need to make appropriate runtime checks like you would in JS. There is no way to satisfy the compiler since there is no way to guarantee that the properties of a runtime object are in an interface which gets compiled away.

Comment: Not strictly speaking IMO a duplicate but see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64564527/typescript-check-if-a-string-exists-as-an-interface-key) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72627449/how-to-correctly-type-the-keys-of-an-object-in-typescript).

Answer (score -1):

Add an intersection to explicitly require keys of Thing to be string:

```
type Thing = {
  name?: string;
  age?: number;
  location?: {
    x: number,
    y: number
  }
} & { [key: string]: any };
```

Comment: That's like not being able to get into your house because your key doesn't fit the front door and solving the problem by just removing the lock entirely.

Answer (score -1):

You could make use of [Partial Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype):

```
type Thing = {
  name?: string;
  age?: number;
  location?: {
    x: number;
    y: number;
  };
};

const things: Thing = { name: 'Jim', age: 32, location: { x: 1, y: 2 } };
const things2: Thing = { name: 'Jim' };

const things3 = {} as Partial<Record<keyof Thing, any>>;

Object.entries(things).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  const thingKey = key as keyof Thing;

  if (things[thingKey] !== things2[thingKey]) {
    things3[thingKey] = value as Thing[keyof Thing];
  }
});
```

`Partial<Thing>` makes all properties optional while keeping type safety. You can then cast `key` as `keyof Thing` to ensure validity. As well as `value` as `Thing[keyof Thing]` so TS knows it exists in `Thing`.

Your result should be this:

```
{ age: 32, location: { x: 1, y: 2 } }
```

Comment: Deleted my comments. Nice.